# PrimeFaces <p:poll> refresh invalidates backing bean member if bean ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces UI library and JSF 2.

I have a backing bean:

```
public class JobMgmtBean extends ClientBeanBase implements Serializable
```

and

```
public class ClientBeanBase extends BeanBase
```

(so inheritance is `JobMgmtBean:ClientBeanBase:BeanBase`).

I wanted to set my `JobMgmtBean` from request scoped to view scoped, but after a while my `sessionVars` which is defined in `BeanBase` **becomes null** and the bean is not functional anymore.

I initialize `sessionVars` in the `BeanBase` like this:

```
protected Map<String,Object> sessionVars = null;

ex = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
sessionVars = ex.getSessionMap();
```

I refresh some of my PrimeFaces UI components on the page every 5 seconds (using `<p:poll interval="5"...>`), and after a few refreshes `sessionVars` becomes null.

Why does this happen?

Comment: ClientBeanBase and BeanBase are also annotated as @ManagedBean? if so, what scopes do they have? where is the code "sessionVars = ex.getSessionMap();"? in constructor? postconstruct?

Comment: `ClientBeanBase` and `BeanBase` are not managed beans, so no scope for them. `sessionVars` is in initBeanBase() which is called in `JobMgmtBean` constructor. Does that help?

Comment: I ment BeanBase::intiBeanBase().

Comment: can you check if the bean becomes constructed again during an ajax request? (add a breakpoint or system.out.print in constructor or @PostConstruct

Comment: No, JobMgmtBean gets created only once. :-(

Comment: Also, some other classes also extend from BeanBase.

Comment: can you check Objects put into sessionVars are all serializable, view scoped beans needs to be Serializable and hence all the instances it refers to.

Comment: That problem I did see, and fixed. I had one class inside `JobMgmtBean` that was not serialized, and I got error report when I opened the page: `SEVERE: Exiting serializeView - Could not serialize state...`. Then I serialized the class, and all is ok now, that error is not reported anymore. Would it be possible that ClientBeanBase and BeanBase could have non serializable object, and that this is not reported i.e. crased the app?

Comment: @Danijel in my experience whenever I have used view scoped and any non serializable reference was present it was always reported.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't report that BeanBase was not serialized, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewScoped beans require objects to be Serialized, and my class extends many classes with too many object which all need to be Serialized which is not possible. This means that I can not use ViewScoped at all here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use View scope provided you can assemble the state of object during de-serialization.

Java provides method hooks for a serializable class where you can perform custom logic.

```
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException {
        //custom logic
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException  {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        // custom logic
    }
```

Any bean reference you think you dont want serialize you can mark it as **transient**.

```
private transient Bean bean.
```

> this bean wont get serialized but the problem is you are responsible
>   to set the reference back when it is deserailized in method hook
>   "readObject"

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException  {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        // custom logic
        this.bean = ................ 
    }
```